# Are ℓp spaces discrete spaces?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, lp-spaces

The sequence spaces $ℓp$ are defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#%E2%84%93p_spaces.

My question is: since sequences are basically just functions on the domain of $\mathbb{N}$ (or $\mathbb{Z}$), the sequence space should be a discrete space, am I right?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Isn't $l_p(\mathbb R)$ a vector space over $\mathbb R$? so it is not discrete

Comment: @monagredson Well, $\Bbb R^2$ is basically just a space of functions $\{0,1\}\to\Bbb R$, but I don't think that this objection of yours carries on.

Comment: What do you mean by a discrete space? The topology is discrete? There is a topology on that set that is discrete but usually one speaks of the normed topology, which isn't

Comment: @Keshav You are right, I didn´t realize that the elements of $l_p$ are sequences, which are discrete structures, but all the sequences (elements) together do not form a discrete structure, since they are over $\mathbb{R}$. Thank you all for the responses, since I am quite new into this subject.

Comment: @Gae.S. How is $R^2$ such space of functions? I do not understand.

Comment: You can identify $f:\{0,1\}\to\Bbb R$ with the pair $(f(0),f(1))$.